# Error CS0117: Namespace.A does not contain definition for Interface

Tags: c#, assemblies, namespaces, compiler-errors

I'm getting the error:

---

'Namespace.A' does not contain a definition for 'MyObjectInterface' and no extension method 'MyObjectInterface' accepting a first argument of type ...

---

I've looked at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=821175) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4aad8at(vs.80).aspx) and neither seems to apply.

The code looks like:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public IObject MyObjectInterface { get; set; }
}

public class A : Base
{
    /**/
}

public class Implementation
{
    public void Method()
    {
        Base obj = new A();
        obj.MyObjectInterface = /* something */; // Error here
    }
}
```

- IObject is defined in a separate assembly, but:

  - IObject is in a separate assembly/namespace
  - Base and A are in the same assembly/namespace each with correct using directives
  - Implementation is in a third separate assembly namespace, also with correct using directives.
- Casting to A before trying to set MyObjectInterface doesn't work
- Specifically, I'm trying to set the value of MyObjectInterface to a mock object (though, I created a fake instead to no avail)

I've tried everything I can think of. Please help before I lose more hair.

*edit*
I can't reproduce the error by creating a test app either, which is why I'm here and why I'm frustrated.

@Reed Copsey: /* something */ is either an NUnit.DynamicMock(IMailer).MockInstance or a Fake object I created that inherits from IObject and just returns canned values.

@Preet Sangha: I checked and no other assembly that is referenced has a definition for an IObject (specifically, it's called an IMailer).

Thing is that intellisense picks up the Property, but when I compile, I get CS0117. I can even 'Go To Definition' in the implementation, and it takes me to where I defined it.

Comment: I've created a dummy project, and using IObject in separate assembly, and this code in a another. Everything is compiling fine. I strongly suspect there is different issue that is causing this problem. Have you confirmed by ensuring at references to IObject are not picked up from another place from the implementation you require.

Comment: What is the error reporting for "Type" and how is "/* something */" defined?  Those two issues are critical for answering you properly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is somewhat consistent with the error you get when you are referencing an assembly that uses a type defined in another assembly and you are not referencing the dependency's dependency.

To fix this add a reference to the assembly containing `IObject` as a reference to the project containing `Implementation`.

Here is little diagram. If Assembly2 exposes a type defined in Assembly3 then ASsembly1 must reference Assembly3 as well. The below situation will not work:

```
_____________             _____________               _____________
| Assembly1  |references  | Assembly2  |references    | Assembly3  |
|           -|------------|->         -|--------------|->          |
|            |            | public     |              | IObject    |
|            |            |  IObject   |              |            |
|            |            |            |              |            |
-------------             -------------               -------------
```

This is only an issue when a type defined in Assembly3 is accessible through Assembly2. This will be in one of the following situations:

- Type defined in Assembly2 derives from a type in Assembly3.
- Method defined in Assembly2 uses a type from Assembly3 as return type or as an argument.
- Type defined in Assembly2 exposes a type from Assembly3 as a property or a public field.

You will need to add a reference to Assembly3 from Assembly1 to make it compile.

```
_____________             _____________               _____________
| Assembly1  |references  | Assembly2  |references    | Assembly3  |
|           -|------------|->         -|--------------|->          |
|            |            | public     |              | IObject    |
|            |references  |  IObject   |              |            |
|           -|------------|------------|--------------|->          |
|            |            |            |              |            |
-------------             -------------               -------------
```